# AWS CloudWatch alarm in "ALARM" state for invocations < 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

A file being dropped into an S3 bucket invokes a lambda. I have set up an alert to notify me when nothing has been dropped into the bucket in a 24-hour period, that is, no lambda invocations.

However, for one of my environments I am not expecting files to land in the bucket regularly, so I want to temporarily disable the alarm by decreasing the invocations threshold to less than zero: `Invocations < 0 for 24 datapoints within 24 hours`.

I am seeing that the alarm is still going into an `ALARM` state after one day, despite the threshold being lowered from `1` to `0`. I have tried with `-1`, too, but this did not help.

How can I temporarily disable this alarm?

Comment: Is it going into the `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` state?

Comment: No, it is going into the `ALARM` state.

Comment: In that case, I should ask how you have configured the alarm to [treat missing data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data).  After some period of complete inactivity, the service being monitored typically stops sending any metrics, so CloudWatch alarms have a third "insufficient data" state, along with several options for keeping you out of that state and into one of the other two.  I may be leading you in the wrong direction, but I think we should eliminate this as a factor.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Michael. I can see that the alarm is configured to treat missing data as `bad (breaching threshold)`. Hopefully changing it to `good (not breaching threshold)` will solve the issue. Cheers!